# Publish message on geometry_msgs/TwistStamped from terminal

Tags: ros-kinetic, geometry-msgs

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi there
I'm back to using ROS after a few years break and would appreciate some help.

I'm trying to publish a message from the terminal but are having trouble getting the arguments right. Could anyone help me with this?

The message is  geometry_msgs/TwistStamped: http://docs.ros.org/jade/api/geometry_msgs/html/msg/TwistStamped.html

```
std_msgs/Header header
  uint32 seq
  time stamp
  string frame_id
geometry_msgs/Twist twist
  geometry_msgs/Vector3 linear
    float64 x
    float64 y
    float64 z
  geometry_msgs/Vector3 angular    
    float64 x
    float64 y
    float64 z
```

I have tried all sorts of combinations but no luck.

One example:

```
rostopic pub -r 100 /mavros/setpoint_velocity/cmd_vel geometry_msgs/TwistStamped "{header: auto, twist.linear:[1, 2, 3], twist.angular:[1, 1, 1]}"
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/280828/publish-message-on-geometry_msgs/twiststamped-from-terminal/) by [eirikaso](https://answers.ros.org/users/10741/eirikaso/) on ROS Answers with karma: 108 on 2018-01-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

After entering this much of the command:

```
rostopic pub -r 100 /mavros/setpoint_velocity/cmd_vel
```

You should be able to press Tab a couple times and it will fill in a blank message for you. I don't think you need to specify geometry_msgs/TwistStamped.

---

Originally posted by [AndyZe](https://answers.ros.org/users/21281/andyze/) with karma: 2331 on 2018-01-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [eirikaso](https://answers.ros.org/users/10741/eirikaso/) on 2018-01-25**:
That worked, thanks.